# Find all possible combinations of $A, A, A, B, B$

Tags: combinatorics

10 year old daughter has this problem.

She knows that all possible combinations of $A,B,C,D$ are $4! = 24  $
She figured it like this:

If I write down $A$ first, it has $4$ possible places.
If I write down $B$ next, it has $3$ possible places for each of the places of $A (4.3)$
If I write down $C$ next, it has $2$ possible places for each of the above placings $(4.3.2)$
If I write down $D$ last, it has $1$ possible place for each of the above placings $(4.3.2.1)$

How can she extend this method to find out all possible combinations of $A,A,A,B,B$ ?

Comment: ${5\choose 2}=10$ places to put the two B's, then the A's are determined perforce.

Comment: Thank you!  How can I explain this in the terms that her maths teacher taught them (described above) though?

Comment: Generating series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are making a $5$-letter word, so we have $5$ slots to fill using $3$ A's and $2$ B's.

Maybe the leftmost B is in the first (leftmost) slot. Then there are $4$ places to put the second B.

Maybe the leftmost B is in the second slot. Then there are $3$ places to put the second B.

Maybe the leftmost B is in the third slot. Then there are $2$ places to put the second B.

Maybe the leftmost B is in the fourth slot. Then there is only $1$ place to put the second B.

Add up. We get $4+3+2+1$.

Comment: Daughter now remembers that this is how the maths teacher explained it.  :-)

Comment: ...so I have to mark this as the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If we are dealing with bigger numbers, say $7$ A's and $5$ B's, the method of the other solutions is much superior. But I figured for age $10$ a more concrete approach is likely the one expected.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

First pretend that the $A$'s and $B$'s are actually different - for example, say they're numbered $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $B_1$, $B_2$. Then this is the same problem you mentioned, and there are $5!$ ways to arrange the letters.

The problem is that you'll obtain many arrangements that differ only because of the numbering. So your problem is to determine how many arrangements there are differing only by the numbering that correspond to a single arrangement where the numbering is ignored.

For example, how many arrangements *including* numbers correspond to ABAAB? Can you get this by a calculation?

Comment: OK, we said, There are 5! combinations of numbered letters.  Then we looked at the sample combination A1,A2,A3,B1,B2.  There are 6 possible combinantions of the As, and 2 possible combinations of Bs, so total = 12 possible combinations.  But all these 12 possible combinations are really only 1 combination, because the letters are not numbered.  So, every 12 combinations of the numbered letter, is really only 1 combination of the non-numbered letters.  So the total number of combinations is 120 / 12 = 10.  (daughter got there first :-o )

Comment: Yes, that's a good explanation. Now can you try with 10 A's, 4 B's and 7 C's?

Comment: Daughter has already made another example for herself and done it!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are $5!$ combinations of $A_1A_2A_3B_1B_2$ if we first assume the $A$'s and $B$'s to be distinct. In all these combinations $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ can appear in $3!$ different ways, but they would all give the same word, so we'll have to divide by $3!$. Given the same argument for $B_1$ and $B_2$ we have to divide once again with $2!$, so the answer would be $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$.

Comment: Sorry, it's been corrected. It just means that in any combinations of the letters $A_1A_2A_3B_1B_2$, $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$ can appear in 6 different ways; $A_1A_2A_3,\enspace A_1A_3A_2,\enspace A_2A_1A_3,\enspace A_2A_3A_1,\enspace A_3A_1A_2,\enspace A_3A_2A_1$, but all of these are similar since $A_3=A_2=A_1$, so we divide by the number of words that would look the same, in this case $3!$, or $6$. You can make a similar argument for the $B$'s. If you already understood it in one way that's fine.